# Having trouble with adding a section to a panel at runtime: IgnitProperties has no attribute 'Add'

Tags: python, scripting, interface, panel

I asked a similar question quite a while ago but I'm still having trouble with this. For those that didn't see my last question, basically I want to replicate what the background image system does, or at least the panel. I want to have an add button and an X button, and when the add button is pressed by the user, a section is added to the panel and that can be done as many times as the user is willing to click it. Then added to each one of those sections is the X button, and when that X button is clicked, it removes that section, just like the background images. I have this code so far, I've only added the parts of that should concern:

```
class IgnitProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    collapse = BoolProperty(
        name = "Collapse",
        description = "Allows the MacBook Controller to be collapsable",
        default = True,
        update = lambda self, context: common_update(self, context, 'collapse')
    )


class AddMacBook(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add MacBook"
    bl_idname = "macbook_controller.add_macbook"

    def execute(self, context):
        item = context.scene.ignit_panel.add()
        def unique_name(names):
            # from wm.py
            prop = "MacBook"
            prop_new = prop
            i = 1
            while prop_new in names:
                prop_new = prop + str(i)
                i += 1

            return prop_new
        item.title = unique_name([i.title for i in context.scene.ignit_panel])
        return{'FINISHED'}

class RemoveMacBook(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Remove MacBook"
    bl_idname = "macbook_controler.remove_macbook"

    del_item = bpy.props.IntProperty(name='item index to remove')

    def execute(self, context):
        context.scene.ignit_panel.remove(self.del_item)
        return{'FINISHED'}

class IGLayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "MacBook Controller"
    bl_idname = "macbook_controller.macbook_controller"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        split = layout.split()
        scene = context.scene
        camera = scene.camera.data
        obj = context.object

        # Add
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        layout.operator("macbook_controller.add_macbook")

        for idx,ignit_options in enumerate(scene.ignit_panel):
            # Box
            box = layout.box()
            row = box.row()

        # Collapsable Menu
        collapse = scene.ignit_panel.collapse

        if collapse == True:
            row.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "collapse",
                icon="TRIA_DOWN",
                icon_only=True, emboss=False
            )
        else:
            row.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "collapse",
            icon="TRIA_RIGHT",
            icon_only=True, emboss=False
        )

        # Title (per object)
        row.label(text = "MacBook")

        row.operator("macbook_controler.remove_macbook", text="", icon = "X", emboss = False).del_item = idx

        # Collapsing everything inside the box
        if not ignit_options.collapse:
            #This is the section that I want to be drawn every time the add button is clicked




def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.ignit_panel = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=IgnitProperties)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister__module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.ignit_panel

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

No errors in the console at first, but as soon as I try to click one of those buttons, it tells me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users....../macbook_controller.py", line 1202 in execute
AttributeError: 'IgnitProperties' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: in the register func it should be `bpy.types.Scene.ignit_panel = bpy.props.CollectionProperty()`  so you can call `add()`  ( it has to be collection prop not a pointer )

Comment: Ok, thanks, I now have another error, I added that to my description, but the good news is that I see my box appearing as expected, there's just nothing in it.

Comment: as it says IgnitProperties type has only a boolean variable, there is no title inside IgnitProperties,  you can add a stringPropety inside if you want  and call it title

Comment: Well if I comment that part out it doesn't give errors, but the boxes are still empty, I'll add an image to the description.

Comment: this `collapse = ignit_options.collapse`  should be this  `collapse = ignit_options.collapse`  and change it to this `row.prop(ignit_options,  .......)`  or this `row.prop(ignit_options.collapse,  .......)` I can't test on my current system now sorry

Comment: also  fix the indentation you are not adding any thing inside the loop

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out, and the indentation is just from adding the code to here, it does some weird stuff sometimes when I put code onto here...

Comment: Ok, getting there! One more error, I think it's the last one. I'll add it to the description

Comment: did you try this instead `row.prop(ignit_options.collapse, .......)`

Comment: What are you trying to display ( which property exactly )

Comment: Yes I did try that, no success. I'm trying to display a whole lot of properties, about a dozen of them, I haven't got them in the description though. Also, should we move this to chat?

Comment: as i said i can't test on my machine , and we can move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33992/discussion-between-matthew-inglis-and-chebhou).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there were a whole lot of small errors that contributed to fixing this. Here were the steps required to fix it.

1) Change `bpy.types.Scene.ignit_panel = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=IgnitProperties)` to `bpy.types.Scene.ignit_panel = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=IgnitProperties)`
(PointerProperty to CollectionProperty)

2) All of the `scene.ignit_panel` in the draw function had to be changed to `ignit_options`

3) The last for loop had to be removed (this was not actually shown in the code above, but it was after `if not ignit_options.collapse:`)

4) The collapsible menu if statement had to be moved into the for loop just above it